# Double Commander: How to set up a command/action to act on two selected files?

Tags: double-commander

Ideally I'd like to be able to select two files in Double Commander (Ubuntu) and then right click to run an external file compare tool on the two files.  I know I can do this from the command line by pasting the two file names there, but for the amount of times that I do this that process is clunky and I'd like to have a faster way to do this from two selected files.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked in the post
[custom command question](https://doublecmd.h1n.ru/viewtopic.php?t=2515).

Here is the answer :

> You could add a new toolbar button. The example uses the Linux cp
> command to copy all selected items (files or directories) from your
> active panel to the directory of your target panel
>
> ```
> Button type: External
> Command: cp
> Parameters: -r %f %Dt
> Hotkey: Whatever you like
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> - The -r parameter belongs to the cp command and makes sure that directories are copied recursively
> - %f returns a list of all selected files/directories. File names with spaces are OK.
> - %Dt returns the target directory
>
> Recommended reading: Help file, chapter 3.2 Button toolbar